# Running SVM code in SciPy over multiple cores?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, svm

I'm new to the field of data science. I want to train a model using SVM on a dataset with 500k rows and 81 columns.

So far, it's taking hours to run this model in SciPy. I have access to 100+ compute nodes with 16 cores a piece, but not sure how to take advantage of this due to my lack of knowledge in how I should be running this SVM code.

Can someone point me in the right direction for how I should go about solving this resource problem?

Answer (score 0):

What kernel function are you using?

SVMs doesn't scale very well. The run time is O(n^3) where n is the number of training samples.

If you don't use a kernel function you can create a spark cluster and you can use spark mllib SVM that is a linear classifier:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html

If you use a non linear kernel function then you can use LIBIRWLS, that is multicore so you can use the parallelization on a machine using 16 cores:

https://github.com/RobeDM/LIBIRWLS

Comment: Do you have any idea how long something like this should take in reality?

Comment: This is ran using radial basis kernel

Comment: You don't know in advance the run time (it depends on the number of support vectors at the end of the training). For 500.000 the run time, if you use libsvm probably will be several hours. If you want a fast run time you can use an approximation to the SVM, take a look to these libraries (BudgetedSVM http://www.dabi.temple.edu/budgetedsvm/ and LIBIRWLS: https://github.com/RobeDM/LIBIRWLS) that contain an algorithm that is a simplification.